# Scope within recursive function?

Tags: javascript, variables, recursion, scope

Edited for clarity:

The code aims to remember where it's been with the valid property and there are a finite number of possible paths.

For example, in a 4x4 grid: start at (1,1), then can you go N, S, E, or W? N (which is (1,2)) is the new start. From (1,2): N? No. E? Yes. Start again at (2,2). Continue until all possible paths have been explored.

```js
function getTestSubjects(current){
 //returns an array unique to current
}
var successes = [];
var currentPath = [];

function nextStep(current){
 currentPath.push(current);
    current.valid = false;
 if (currentPath.length === desiredLength){
  successes.push(currentPath);

  //line X
  return
 }
 var testSubjects = getTestSubjects(current);
 for(i=0;i<testSubjects.length;i++){
     if(testSubjects[i].valid === true){
           nextStep(testSubjects[i])
        }
    }
}
```

My question pertains to the locality of variables in recursive functions.
For every time nextStep() is called, is a unique local variable testSubjects created,
or does the same variable (local to the first call of nextStep()) change what it holds?

When the for loop reaches a point where testSubjects[i].valid === false, will it return to the previous call of nextStep and keep looping?

Also, if at lineX, I write currentPath = [] to clear the path and continue searching for other successful paths, will it affect the currentPath already pushed to the successes array?

I hope this makes sense. I'm still a baby programmer. Please ask if you need any clarification and thanks in advance!

Comment: `testSubjects[i].valid = false` does not occur anywhere in the script you've included. Also, in your line `if(testSubjects[i].valid = true)` you need to use an equality operator, probably `===`. That said, if `valid` is a boolean type, you can just do the following: `if(testSubjects[i].valid)`.

Comment: Oh, good point! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a unique local variable is made everytime.
Yes it will return and continue the for loop.

I dont think its wise to continue to search after having found a successful path. depending on the unique array you create.. seems like you could have an endless loop?

is your unique array getting smaller and smaller?